# Run/Debug JUnit 5 Tests using Gradle and Mapstruct

Tags: spring, debugging, gradle, junit5, mapstruct

I am trying to run and debug JUnit 5 Tests that use Mapstruct using both Visual Studio Code and Eclipse, but with no luck.

What works is to run the Test goal on Gradle. It runs the tests properly and show a result but when I try to run or debug the same test "manually" using the IDE, it throws an exception, always related to not being able to find the Mapper implementations or not being able to Autowire the clases, etc.

I have tried different things but with similar results, such as Autowire the Mapper, creating an instance of the Mapper in a method using @Before annotation... but always with no success.

Here is an example of a Mapper:

**AddressMapper.java**

```
package com.myorg.ccr.simulator.b2b.mapping;

import com.myorg.myproject.model.AddressDTO;
import com.myorg.myproject.model.StateDTO;
import com.myorg.xsd.b2b.upsertcustomer.Address;

import org.mapstruct.AfterMapping;
import org.mapstruct.BeanMapping;
import org.mapstruct.InheritInverseConfiguration;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
    unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
    uses = {DateMapper.class, UUIDMapper.class, StateMapper.class})
public interface AddressMapper {
    AddressMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AddressMapper.class);

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(target = "externalAddressId", source = "externalAddressId")
    @Mapping(target = "street1", source = "streetAddress")
    @Mapping(target = "street2", source = "streetAddress2")
    @Mapping(target = "postOfficeBox", source = "POBox")
    @Mapping(target = "city", source = "city")
    @Mapping(target = "postalCode", source = "postalCode")
    @Mapping(target = "salutation", source = "recipientSalutation")
    @Mapping(target = "phone", source = "recipientPhone")
    @Mapping(target = "comments", source = "comments")
    AddressDTO addressToAddressDTO(Address address);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Address addressDTOToAddress(AddressDTO address);

    @AfterMapping
    default void setStatus(Address address, @MappingTarget AddressDTO addressDTO) {
        StateDTO state = StateMapper.INSTANCE.addressToState(address);
        addressDTO.setStatus(state);
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void setSourceCreatedUpdatedDate(Address address, @MappingTarget AddressDTO addressDTO) {
        if (address != null) {
            addressDTO.setSourceCreatedDate(DateMapper.asDate(address.getSourceCreatedDate()));
            addressDTO.setSourceUpdatedDate(DateMapper.asDate(address.getSourceUpdatedDate()));
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void useTypeToAddressNumber(Address address, @MappingTarget AddressDTO addressDTO) {
        if (address != null && address.getType() != null && !address.getType().isEmpty()) {

            switch (address.getType()) {
                case "Billing":
                    addressDTO.setAddressNumber(1);
                    break;
                case "Delivery":
                    addressDTO.setAddressNumber(2);
                    break;
                case "Packing Station":
                    addressDTO.setAddressNumber(3);
                    break;
                case "Post Office":
                    addressDTO.setAddressNumber(4);
                    break;
                default:
                    addressDTO.setAddressNumber(null);
            }   
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void addressNumberToType(AddressDTO addressDTO, @MappingTarget Address address) {
        if (addressDTO != null && addressDTO.getAddressNumber() != null) {

            switch (addressDTO.getAddressNumber()) {
                case 1:
                    address.setPrimaryFlag("Y");
                    address.setType("Billing");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    address.setPrimaryFlag("N");
                    address.setType("Delivery");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    address.setPrimaryFlag("N");
                    address.setType("Packing Station");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    address.setPrimaryFlag("N");
                    address.setType("Post Office");
                    break;
                default:
                    address.setPrimaryFlag("N");
                    address.setType(null);
            }   
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void contactFullname(Address address, @MappingTarget AddressDTO addressDTO) {
        String firstName = address.getRecipientFirstName();
        String lastName = address.getRecipientLastName();
        if (firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty() && lastName != null && !lastName.isEmpty()) {
            addressDTO.setContactFullname(firstName + " " + lastName);
        } else if ((firstName == null || firstName.isEmpty()) && lastName != null && !lastName.isEmpty()) {
            addressDTO.setContactFullname(lastName);
        } else if (firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty()  && (lastName == null || lastName.isEmpty())) {
            addressDTO.setContactFullname(firstName);
        } 
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void addressRecipientName(AddressDTO addressDTO, @MappingTarget Address address) {
        if (addressDTO != null && addressDTO.getContactFullname() != null && !addressDTO.getContactFullname().isEmpty()) {
            address.setRecipientFirstName(addressDTO.getContactFullname());
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void setActiveFlag(AddressDTO addressDTO, @MappingTarget Address address) {
        String activeFlag = "N";
        if (addressDTO != null) { 
            activeFlag = StateMapper.INSTANCE.stateToActiveFlag(addressDTO.getStatus());
        } 
        address.setActiveFlag(activeFlag);
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void setDeletedFlag(AddressDTO addressDTO, @MappingTarget Address address) {
        String deletedFlag = "N";
        if (addressDTO != null) { 
            deletedFlag = StateMapper.INSTANCE.stateToDeletedFlag(addressDTO.getStatus());
        } 
        address.setDeletedFlag(deletedFlag);
    }

    @AfterMapping
    default void setCountry(AddressDTO addressDTO, @MappingTarget Address address) {
        String country = null;
        if (addressDTO != null && addressDTO.getCountry() != null && !addressDTO.getCountry().isEmpty()) { 
            country = addressDTO.getCountry();
        } 
        address.setISOCountryCode(country);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a Test:

**AddressMapperTest.java**

```
package com.myorg.ccr.simulator.b2b.messaging.mapping;

import com.myorg.myproject.model.AddressDTO;
import com.myorg.myproject.model.StateDTO;
import com.myorg.ccr.simulator.b2b.mapping.AddressMapper;
import com.myorg.ccr.simulator.b2b.messaging.mapping.helpers.AddressMappingHelper;
import com.myorg.xsd.b2b.upsertcustomer.Address;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class AddressMapperTest {
    private AddressMapper mapper = AddressMapper.INSTANCE;

    @Test
    public void xsdAddressToAddressTest() {
        Address xsdAddress = new Address();

        xsdAddress.setActiveFlag("Y");
        xsdAddress.setDeletedFlag("N");
        xsdAddress.setType("Billing");
        xsdAddress.setPrimaryFlag("N");
        xsdAddress.setExternalAddressId("15106794");
        xsdAddress.setStreetAddress("Some Street Name 70 E/24");
        xsdAddress.setStreetAddress2("Some Building info 123");
        xsdAddress.setPOBox("08905");
        xsdAddress.setCity("BiaÅ‚ystok");
        xsdAddress.setPostalCode("15-181");
        xsdAddress.setISOCountryCode("PL");
        xsdAddress.setRecipientLastName("Mustermann");
        xsdAddress.setRecipientFirstName("Max");
        xsdAddress.setRecipientSalutation("Mr.");
        xsdAddress.setRecipientPhone("512341234");
        xsdAddress.setAddressInvalidFlag("Y");
        xsdAddress.setComments("A comment from the user.");
        xsdAddress.setSourceCreatedDate("2016-06-14T21:19:33+02:00");
        xsdAddress.setSourceUpdatedDate("2019-09-05T11:26:20+02:00");

        AddressDTO address = mapper.addressToAddressDTO(xsdAddress);
        assertThat(address.getId()).isNull();
        assertThat(address.getStatus()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(address.getStatus().getValue()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(address.getStatus().getValue()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(address.getExternalAddressId()).isEqualTo("15106794");
        assertThat(address.getAddressNumber()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(address.getStreet1()).isEqualTo("Some Street Name 70 E/24");
        assertThat(address.getStreet2()).isEqualTo("Some Building info 123");
        assertThat(address.getCity()).isEqualTo("BiaÅ‚ystok");
        assertThat(address.getPostalCode()).isEqualTo("15-181");
        assertThat(address.getPostOfficeBox()).isEqualTo("08905");
        assertThat(address.getCountry()).isNull(); //This may change
        assertThat(address.getContactFullname()).isEqualTo("Max Mustermann");
        assertThat(address.getSalutation()).isEqualTo("Mr.");
        assertThat(address.getPhone()).isEqualTo("512341234");
        assertThat(address.getComments()).isEqualTo("A comment from the user.");
        assertThat(address.getSourceCreatedDate()).isEqualTo(OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-06-14T21:19:33+02:00",
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
        assertThat(address.getSourceUpdatedDate()).isEqualTo(OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-09-05T11:26:20+02:00",
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    }

    @Test
    public void addressDTOToXSDAddressTest() {
        AddressDTO addressDTO = new AddressDTO();
        StateDTO state = new StateDTO();
        state.setValue(1);
        addressDTO.setStatus(state);
        addressDTO.setExternalAddressId("15106794");
        addressDTO.setAddressNumber(1);
        addressDTO.setStreet1("Some Street Name 70 E/24");
        addressDTO.setStreet2("Some Building info 123");
        addressDTO.setPostOfficeBox("08905");
        addressDTO.setCity("BiaÅ‚ystok");
        addressDTO.setPostalCode("15-181");
        addressDTO.setCountry("PL");
        addressDTO.setContactFullname("Max Mustermann");
        addressDTO.setSalutation("Mr.");
        addressDTO.setPhone("512341234");
        addressDTO.setComments("A comment from the user.");
        addressDTO.setSourceCreatedDate(OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-06-14T21:19:33+02:00",
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
        addressDTO.setSourceUpdatedDate(OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-09-05T11:26:20+02:00",
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

        Address address = mapper.addressDTOToAddress(addressDTO);
        assertThat(address.getActiveFlag()).isEqualTo("Y"); //This may change
        assertThat(address.getDeletedFlag()).isEqualTo("N"); //This may change
        assertThat(address.getExternalAddressId()).isEqualTo("15106794");
        assertThat(address.getPrimaryFlag()).isEqualTo("Y");
        assertThat(address.getStreetAddress()).isEqualTo("Some Street Name 70 E/24");
        assertThat(address.getStreetAddress2()).isEqualTo("Some Building info 123");
        assertThat(address.getCity()).isEqualTo("BiaÅ‚ystok");
        assertThat(address.getPostalCode()).isEqualTo("15-181");
        assertThat(address.getPOBox()).isEqualTo("08905");
        assertThat(address.getISOCountryCode()).isEqualTo("PL"); //This may change
        assertThat(address.getRecipientFirstName()).isEqualTo("Max Mustermann");
        assertThat(address.getRecipientSalutation()).isEqualTo("Mr.");
        assertThat(address.getRecipientPhone()).isEqualTo("512341234");
        assertThat(address.getComments()).isEqualTo("A comment from the user.");
        assertThat(address.getSourceCreatedDate()).isEqualTo("2016-06-14T21:19:33+02:00");
        assertThat(address.getSourceUpdatedDate()).isEqualTo("2019-09-05T11:26:20+02:00");
    }

    @Test
    public void dynamicXSDAddressToAddressDTOTest() {
        AddressMappingHelper mappingHelper = new AddressMappingHelper();

        while (mappingHelper.hasNext()) {
            mappingHelper.nextXSDAddress();
            Address xsdAddress =  mappingHelper.getExpectedAddress();
            AddressDTO address = mapper.addressToAddressDTO(xsdAddress);
            AddressDTO expectedAddress = mappingHelper.getExpectedAddressDTO();
            assertThat(address).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expectedAddress);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void dynamicAddressDTOToXSDAddressTest() {
        AddressMappingHelper mappingHelper = new AddressMappingHelper();

        while (mappingHelper.hasNext()) {
            mappingHelper.nextXSDAddress();
            AddressDTO addressDTO =  mappingHelper.getExpectedAddressDTO();
            Address address = mapper.addressDTOToAddress(addressDTO);
            Address expectedAddress = mappingHelper.getExpectedAddressFromDTO();
            System.out.println(address);
            System.out.println(expectedAddress);
            assertThat(address).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expectedAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the build.gradle file:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    jmsVersion        = '2.0.1'
    jaxbApiVersion = '2.2.7'
    flywayVersion = '5.2.1'

    // tests
    junitJuniper = '5.1.1'
    junitGradlePlatformVersion = '1.1.0'
    assertJCoreVersion = '3.14.0'

    mapstructVersion = "1.3.0.Final"

    swaggerCodgenVersion = '3.0.13'
    jacksonThreetenVersion = '2.6.4'

  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "checkstyle"

group = 'com.myorg.ccr'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    credentials {
      username = "$mavenUser"
      password = "$mavenPassword"
    }
    url "https://myorg.jfrog.io/myorg/libs-snapshot"
  }
  maven {
    credentials {
      username = "$mavenUser"
      password = "$mavenPassword"
    }
    url "https://myorg.jfrog.io/myorg/libs-release"
  }
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/schema'
    }
  }
}

configurations {
  jaxb_generateSources
}

dependencies {
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
  annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

  implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: springBootVersion
  implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion
  implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api
  implementation group: 'javax.jms', name: 'javax.jms-api', version: jmsVersion
  implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '5.1.9.RELEASE'

  implementation group: 'com.tibco', name: 'tibjms', version: '8.2.1'
  implementation group: 'com.myorg.ccr.client', name: 'customer-client', version: '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
  compile group: 'com.myorg.login', name: 'login-lib-java-spring', version: '1.5.0-SNAPSHOT'

  runtimeOnly group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql'
  runtimeOnly group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2'
  implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: flywayVersion

  testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitJuniper"
  testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitJuniper"
  testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:$assertJCoreVersion"
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
  testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")

  jaxb_generateSources(
    [group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version: jaxbApiVersion],
    [group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: jaxbApiVersion],
  )

  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
  compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

  implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}"
  annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"

  // If you are using mapstruct in test code
  testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"

  compile "io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:$swaggerCodgenVersion"
  compile "com.github.joschi.jackson:jackson-datatype-threetenbp:$jacksonThreetenVersion"
}

clean {
  delete 'src/schema'
}

task jaxb_generateSources {


  System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
  def jaxbTargetDir = file("src/schema")

  doLast {
    ext.generateSources = { packageName, xsdSchemaLocation ->
      ant.taskdef(
              name: 'xjc',
              classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask',
              classpath: configurations.jaxb_generateSources.asPath
      )
      ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir

      ant.xjc(
              destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',
              package: packageName,
              schema: xsdSchemaLocation,
              encoding: 'UTF-8'
      )
    }

    jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()

    // b2c
    generateSources('com.myorg.xsd.upsertcustomer', 'src/main/resources/b2c.xsd/doAsyncUpsertCustomer_BDM_DST.xsd')
    // b2b
    generateSources('com.myorg.xsd.b2b.upsertcustomer', 'src/main/resources/b2b/xsd/doAsyncUpsertAccount_BDM_DST.xsd')

  }
}

compileJava {
  dependsOn jaxb_generateSources
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  // TODO: Is actual an integration and no unit test
  exclude '**/ContactControllerTest.class'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
  group = 'verification'
  include '**/ContactControllerTest.class'
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
  exclude '**/b2bkam/**'
}

checkstyle {
  config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile("${rootDir}/config/checkstyle/checkstyle_ccr-simulator_v1.xml")
  toolVersion '8.11'
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Aitor

Comment: Without first generating the mappers the test will fail as there is no mapper. Either run the build or install the MapStruct plugin.

Comment: Done that, it doesn't work. I guess that on Tests the Mappings are not being compiled

Comment: Done what? You need to have the plugin for the IDE or just run the Gradle build from your IDE.